# How to make __name__ == '__main__' when running module

Tags: python

More specifically, I have a file

file file1.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = 1
```

and from file file2.py, I want to do something like

```
import file1
print file1.a
```

without modifying file1.py

Comment: i bet that if you tell a reason why you need this, we could give you a better way to implement it.

Comment: Describing the task at hand could help with a better solution

Comment: It's still nice to know if this is possible, whether or not it's a good idea.

Comment: phihag answered my questions, but FYI I have a bunch of python files that create a particular object.  I am writing a script to compare the outputs.  And if your next question is what is the point of the python files, they do create a bunch of output files, but it is a lot easier for me to compare the python object instead of parsing the output files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import imp
m = imp.find_module('file1')
file1 = imp.load_module('__main__', *m)
```

That being said, you should really think about modifying `file1.py` instead of using this hack.

Comment: The `imp` module has been deprecated since Python 3.4.

Comment: Also, I find your naming a bit confusing; you call the module itself `file1` and the filename/path/description tuple `m`. It would be more clear for me if you reversed the variable names, making `file` the file/path/description and `m` the module.

Answer (score 4):

```
from runpy import run_module
data = run_module("file1", run_name="__main__")
print data["a"]
```

You don't need to mess with the import internals to do things like this any more (and as an added bonus, you will avoid blocking access to your *real* `__main__` module namespace)

Answer (score 3):

You can't; that's the purpose of the main sentinel in the first place. If variables defined in the main sentinel are useful outside of it then they should be defined outside of it to begin with.

Comment: While I agree it's a bad idea, you can(if need be with `execfile` & co). See my answer for a *relatively clean hack* for the `__name__` change.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to declare `a` outside of the `if __name__ == '__main__'` scope.  Right now, it only exists within the scope of that `if` block.

```
a = 0
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = 1
```

Comment: Not true. Statements in python do not have own scopes. Only modules, functions and classes do. In this particular case `a` is global name, and is accessible outside `if` if `if` executed.