# In python, how do I get the same behavior as when __name__ == '__main__':

Tags: python

What is the best way to get this block of code to run when I import main.py rather than run it?

```
#main.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Do something interesting. 


#Do something to have the interesting code run after importing the file. 
import main.py
main.__main__() # wrong of course.
```

Comment: Why not just define functions for the 'interesting code' in the main part of the program?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make __name__ == '__main__' when running module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114251/how-to-make-name-main-when-running-module)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put that code into a function, and call it inside `if`.

```
def main():
    # ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Or simply don't use `if` at all.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need to check anything since the module code is executed when imported for the first time as part of its initialization. In particular, according to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules):

> A module can contain executable statements as well as function definitions. These statements are intended to initialize the module. They are executed only the first time the module is imported somewhere.

If what you need is some code to be executed when the module is imported, but not when the module is execute, then the response from Antoine Pelisse should be the way to go (of course, you could also check `if __name__ != '__main__'` directly).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for that ?

```
#main.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Do something interesting when running main.py directly
    pass
else:
    # Do something when the script in imported
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do this without modifying the `main.py` module (so that "Cat Plus Plus"'s answer doesn't apply):

You can't directly; `__name__` is read-only.  (Edit: This is not actually quite true, as you can use the `imp` module to explicitly specify it when loading the file -- see the first answer on [How to make __name__ == '__main__' when running module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114251/how-to-make-name-main-when-running-module).)

However, you can do it indirectly, with `execfile('main.py')`.