# How do I make a module think its name is __main__?

Tags: python

I have a python script (actually, lots of scripts) with code that is executed only when this module is run as the main script:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("I am the main script")
```

But now I want a testing script to load them as modules, so that it can then poke in their internal state. Rewriting (to turn the code block into a function) is not an option. How do I import a module in such a way that it thinks its name is `__main__`? I'm sure I've seen this done before, with the help of some import library or other, but it's not coming up in my searches.

Comment: Use [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html)

Comment: It's a common approach to test these things via a site-local standard that you use `if __name__ == '__main__': main()`, making the main function callable.

Comment: @Charles indeed that would eliminate the problem. But this is about dozens of student assignments, and I haven't told them to wrap their code in `main()`.

Comment: I guess my question is a duplicate. Here's the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6114411/699305

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to bypass the import machinery, and use `exec` instead:

```
import imp

main = imp.new_module('__main__')
with open(module_filename, 'r') as source:
    exec(source.read(), vars(main))
```

Demo:

```
>>> source = '''\
... if __name__ == '__main__':
...     print("I am the main script")
... '''
>>> import imp
>>> main = imp.new_module('__main__')
>>> exec(source, vars(main))
I am the main script
```

Rather than go this route, consider creating a function you call from the `__main__` guard instead, so you can just import that function for testing:

```
def main():
    print("I am the main script")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Looks good, but is there really no simpler way? I could swear I've seen it done in one step...

Comment: Found it! http://stackoverflow.com/a/6114411/699305. Ok it's two lines, not one.

Comment: @alexis: ah, yes, `imp.find_module()` avoids the need to know the filename up front and `imp.load_module()` does basically what I do with `imp.new_module()` and `exec()` above, with added support for loading a `.pyc` file if it is available.